# Springfox Swagger Ui from existing JSON

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, springfox, swagger-codegen

I have a gradle backed ***SpringBoot*** application where we were originally just creating our 
 *REST controllers* and then using the ***@EnableSwagger2*** annotation to create our swagger UI. This was working just fine, but now we want to transition to an API first approach.

So this means we are now creating our `swagger.json` first, then using `swagger-codegen` to produce generate our Java interfaces / controllers for use in our SpringBoot application. I am now trying to figure out how to just tell `springfox-swagger-ui` to use the `swagger.json` we have created, instead of looking through the java code to produce the UI after the fact. It seems to me this is the correct approach, to avoid any inconsistencies that could possibly arise from essentially `springfox-swagger-ui` from regenerating the `swagger.json` behind the scenes.

How do I go about configuring this behavior? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/indrabasak/springfox-ui-from-json-example) is a working example on how to create a Swagger UI from an existing `swagger.json`.

You need to write a custom Swagger controller having the following endpoints:

1. `/swagger-resources` endpoint which returns a JSON string representation of a 
   `springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SwaggerResource` object.
2. `/swagger-resources/configuration/ui` endpoint which returns a JSON string 
   representation of a `springfox.documentation.swagger.web.UiConfiguration` object.
3. `/swagger-resources/configuration/security` endpoint which returns a JSON string 
   representation of a `springfox.documentation.swagger.web.SecurityConfiguration` object.
4. `/v2/api-docs` endpoint which returns a JSON representation of a Swagger API
   definition.